# What happens to Obito after the 5 minutes of intangibility?

Tags: naruto

Obito is intangible. This intangibility last for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, what happens? I am confused.
Or does  he needs  to keep phasing  through  objects  to remain  intangible?

Comment: Sorry but you're going to have to ask three separate questions instead of all of them in one. This is how this site works.

Comment: i did not understand you question , would you mind elaborating, as your current question is , the answer would be , he will be tangible after 5 min.

Comment: are you talking about how Kamui works

Comment: I know  how kamui works, and I also know how his intangibility works but the question is how long does he remain intangible.

Comment: How long does the intangibility last? Approximately 5 minutes, just like you mentioned in the question. Are you asking how is Obito able to maintain the intangibility for that 5 minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Normally, Obito is not intangible. When he uses Kamui, he can teleport the parts of his body getting hit by attacks into the Kamui dimension, stopping himself from getting damaged. However, the limit of the justsu is five minutes and that is the maximum amount of time he can continually use the jutsu. After the five minutes are up, any further attempts to use Kamui fail, and he presumably requires some time to recharge his chakra before using it again. Your question was kinda confusing, so sorry if I didn't answer properly.